# Load gzipped XML file with simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, gzip, simplexml, decode

I'm trying to load a gzipped XML file using simplexml_load_file() PHP function, but I don't know how to decode it so I can use the data in it.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php or

Comment: @Marek Sebera - This function (gzdecode) is in the manual but doesn't exist in PHP.

Comment: @Pawel: Sure it's part of PHP, you only need to have the extension enabled, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php - it's a very common extension.

Comment: I have this extension enabled and I can't use this function (I have PHP 5.3.6 installed). I can use e.g gzuncompress() so I have this extension enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read it to a string using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/function.file-get-contents) 
decompress it using [`gzuncompress()`](http://www.php.net/function.gzuncompress)
and load string as XML using [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://www.php.net/function.simplexml-load-string).

Comment: Readgzfile() sends it directly to the browser, it doesn't return a string.

Comment: Hmm, why not just `simplexml_load_file("compress.zlib://test.xml");` [instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973672/load-gzipped-xml-file-with-simplexml-load-file/6973867#6973867)?

Comment: @Pawel: Checkout [Streams in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.stream.php), they are a powerful tool of the language, worth to know about. The concept exists in other languages, too, so it's just even better to know about ;)

Answer (score 11):

PHP has [support for zlib compression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) build-in, just prefix the path of your file with the gzip'ed data with `compress.zlib://` and you're done:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("compress.zlib://test.xml");
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: X-Ref: [More links to related questions and PHP bugreports](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14978162/367456)

Answer (score 4):

```
/*EDIT  print_r(gzdecoder(simplexml_load_file('test.xml')));
 (Not sure without testing that the internals of what loads the xml 
  in *_load_file would see the gzipped content as invalid)
*/

   $xml=simplexml_load_string(gzdecoder(file_get_contents('test.xml')));
   print_r( $xml);

function gzdecoder($d){
    $f=ord(substr($d,3,1));
    $h=10;$e=0;
    if($f&4){
        $e=unpack('v',substr($d,10,2));
        $e=$e[1];$h+=2+$e;
    }
    if($f&8){
        $h=strpos($d,chr(0),$h)+1;
    }
    if($f&16){
        $h=strpos($d,chr(0),$h)+1;
    }
    if($f&2){
        $h+=2;
    }
    $u = gzinflate(substr($d,$h));
    if($u===FALSE){
        $u=$d;
    }
    return $u;
}
```