# simplexml_load_file not loading

Tags: http, gzip, simplexml, php

This link to an rss feed doesn't load with `simplexml_load_file`.

- Link: http://www.nationnews.com/site/feed

The link is a valid RSS feed and no it isn't a permission problem everything else loads.

Comment: Please post the PHP code (snippet) you are using, as well as the intended results you want (which fields to parse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to enable error logging and/or reporting to find out more. Also you can check some parameters from the return value and the remote request:

```
$result = simplexml_load_file($url);

var_dump($result, $http_response_header);
```

This will tell you that loading failed, the error messages tell you *why* it failed:

> PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): `http://www.nationnews.com/site/feed/:1`: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /example.php on line 10
>   PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file():  in /example.php on line 10
>   PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /example.php on line 10

And the `$http_response_header` also show you the picture what has been returned from that host:

```
array(23) {
  [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
  [1]=> string(35) "Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2013 10:56:11 GMT"
  [2]=> string(30) "Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)"
  [3]=> string(23) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3"
  [4]=> string(56) "Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=qeaq20mrvrc2u4c403sou6oro2; path=/"
  [5]=> string(38) "Expires: Wed, 20 Feb 2013 08:13:01 GMT"
  [6]=> string(50) "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
  [7]=> string(16) "Pragma: no-cache"
  [8]=> string(84) "Set-Cookie: exp_last_visit=1046015771; expires=Thu, 20-Feb-2014 10:56:11 GMT; path=/"
  [9]=> string(87) "Set-Cookie: exp_last_activity=1361375771; expires=Thu, 20-Feb-2014 10:56:11 GMT; path=/"
  [10]=> string(89) "Set-Cookie: exp_tracker=a%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A11%3A%22%2Fsite%2Ffeed%2F%22%3B%7D; path=/"
  [11]=> string(44) "Last-Modified: Wed, 20 Feb 2013 07:13:01 GMT"
  [12]=> string(40) "Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0"
  [13]=> string(21) "Vary: Accept-Encoding"
  [14]=> string(16) "imagetoolbar: no"
  [15]=> string(17) "Connection: close"
  [16]=> string(37) "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"
  [17]=> string(76) "Set-Cookie: cookiesession1=HTEVZV0HJNK2HARUL2QBDADH8RXYESJB;Path=/;HttpOnly "
  [18]=> string(109) "Set-Cookie: exp_last_visit_cookiesession2=tSzDt6/k20k=;Expires=Thu, 20-Feb-2014 10:56:11 GMT;Path=/;HttpOnly "
  [19]=> string(112) "Set-Cookie: exp_last_activity_cookiesession2=e+FVcqI8+Ck=;Expires=Thu, 20-Feb-2014 10:56:11 GMT;Path=/;HttpOnly "
  [20]=> string(68) "Set-Cookie: exp_tracker_cookiesession2=w+13lT4TxY0=;Path=/;HttpOnly "
  [21]=> string(22) "Content-Encoding: gzip"
  [22]=> string(20) "content-length: 2463"
}
```

According to the HTTP specs that you make use of by using a HTTP uri, the content encoding is:

```
[21]=> string(22) "Content-Encoding: gzip"
```

This is not supported by PHP out of the box with it's HTTP Wrapper so you need to work around that your own

For example by using the [zlib Stream Wrapper:](http://docs.php.net/wrappers.compression):

```
$result = simplexml_load_file('compress.zlib://' . $url);
```

Or with the help of the [`gzdecode`](http://php.net/gzdecode) function:

```
$result = simplexml_load_string(gzdecode(file_get_contents($url)));
```

Full example code with all the variants:

```
$url = 'http://www.nationnews.com/site/feed/';


// stream wrapper:

$result = simplexml_load_file('compress.zlib://' . $url);

var_dump($result, $http_response_header);


// gzdecode:

$result = simplexml_load_string(gzdecode(file_get_contents($url)));

var_dump($result, $http_response_header);


// none (the error case):

$result = simplexml_load_file($url);

var_dump($result, $http_response_header);
```

Related Questions:

- [Uncompress a gzip file from CURL, on php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3002612/367456)
- [Uncompress gzip compressed http response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8895852/367456)
- [PHP: Call to undefined function gzdecode()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9801908/367456)

And the following PHP Bugreports are related (just picked some, this is likely not complete):

- [Bug #52926 - stream_context_set_default() does not work as intended with stream chaining](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52926) (26 Sep 2010)
- [Bug #47925 - PHPClient can't decompress response (transposed uncompress methods?)](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47925) (8 Apr 2009)
- [Doc Bug #29045 - gzopen for URL](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29045) (7 Jul 2005)
- [Request #28051 - gzip accept-encoding for HTTP request](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28051) (19 Apr 2004)

Comment: I will make sure to enable error checking

Comment: @user1807206: Yes, for development, enable all errors. This will save you a lot of time looking in the wrong places. You might find this useful: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) - it's a bit broad and has different answers, but it somewhat shows the different possibilities there are. More Hands-On is [the answer I left in it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14504459/367456).

Answer (score 1):

The rss feed is gziped. This should do the trick:

```
$content =  file_get_contents("http://www.nationnews.com/site/feed/");
$rss = simplexml_load_string(gzinflate(substr($content,10,-8)));
```

See [PHP: Call to undefined function gzdecode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801908/php-call-to-undefined-function-gzdecode) for further details regarding the gzinflate.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. Couldn't find the answer anywhere