# Taking some data from XML file and inputting into sql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Im trying to load the following XML url and some data within into my database.

https://zkillboard.com/api/kills/corporationID/98115872/pastSeconds/7200/xml/

i have the following code:

```
<?php 
// INCLUDE DB CONNECTION FILE
include("includes/connect.php");
// CHANGE THE VALUES HERE
include("includes/config.php");
$url = "https://zkillboard.com/api/kills/corporationID/98115872/pastSeconds/7200/xml/";
// RUN XML DATA READY FOR INSERT
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
// Loop Through Names
$insertValues = array();
$modifiedTS = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
foreach ($xml->result->rowset[0] as $value)
{
        //Prepare the values
        $killID = $value['killID'];
        $solarSystemID = mysql_real_escape_string($value['solarSystemID']);
        $killTime = $value['killTime'];
        $moonID = $value['moonID'];
        $allianceName = $value['allianceName'];
        $corporationName = $value['corporationName'];
        $damageTaken = $value['damageTaken'];
//Create and run ONE INSERT statement (with UPDATE clause)
    $insert = "INSERT INTO `killLog` (killID,solarSystemID,killTime,moonID,allianceName,corporationName,damageTaken,last_modified) VALUES('$killID','$solarSystemID','$killTime','$moonID','$allianceName','$corporationName','$damageTaken','$modifiedTS') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
last_modified = '$modifiedTS'";
mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
};
?>
```

but i get the following errors when accessing the PHP file.

> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(https://zkillboard.com/api/kills/corporationID/98115872/pastSeconds/7200/xml/)
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Non-acceptable encoding. Please use gzip or
>   deflate in
>   /homepages/*****/*****/htdocs/*****/tool/admin/api_killLog.php
>   on line 14
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external entity
>   "https://zkillboard.com/api/kills/corporationID/98115872/pastSeconds/7200/xml/"
>   in
>   /homepages/*****/*****/htdocs/*****/tool/admin/api_killLog.php
>   on line 14
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /*****/*****/htdoc/*****/tool/admin/api_killLog.php on line 19

what am i doing wrong??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load gzipped XML file with simplexml\_load\_file()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973672/load-gzipped-xml-file-with-simplexml-load-file)

Comment: i believe this link might help with my error, do i need to pass gzip in headers or something? how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple case of setting deflate in the curl header.

My code is

```
function get_url_content( $url ) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'xxxxxx Scraper Tool 1.1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    if (function_exists('curl_getopt')) {
        $http_code = curl_getopt($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($http_code != 200) {
            die('Error response from their server - error code: ' . $http_code);
        }
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

If you need a hand with your coding send me a evemail in game, DaveTheGreat